# Background image bigger than viewport

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

Let say I have for smartphone visits to my site

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=360, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and a big background image like 1000x1000.

I only want to be able to fix the size of my background image, even if it's bigger than the viewport, to allow stuff like a zoom.

```
<body style="background: black url('pic.jpg') no-repeat; ">
```

works fine with the original size, but

```
<body style="background: black url('pic.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:750px">
```

limit the size of my picture to the viewport width.

So my question : how can I set the background image size to the any value if it's bigger than the viewport width ?

Answer (score 1):

Set `background-size` to `100% 100%` to stretch and don't preserve aspect ratio.

Set `background-size` to `cover` to stretch, crop redundant parts and preserve aspect ratio.

Set `background-size` to `contain` to stretch, add extra space where needed and preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#bg-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(img/yourphoto.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body id="bg-img">
```